# Jquery .replaceWith() not updating correctly with updated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I've a Form that i'm validating before it get submitted. As name suggests `ValidateForm()` validates the form and `ValidateRange(num)` validates set of fields on the form depending on user selection. Take this from me that Validations are being done correctly.

At the very last `if` statement where i'm checking the result, If I use jQuery `.append()` it's working fine, but i want to replace the validation-text with `replaceWith()` method, but it's not happening.

`result.message` is simply a text string stating which field has a validation problem and points the user to it.

In the `console.log()` i can see the validation pointer messages are coming up correctly as I fix the fields with correct values, but for some reason it keep replacing the `<div id ='ValidationDiv'></div>` with the first pointer message again and again.

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var result = {valid:true, message:"In-Progress"};

    if ($('#firstRangeRadioButton').is(':checked'))
        result = ValidateRange(1);
    else if ($('#secondRangeRadioButton').is(':checked'))
    {
        result = ValidateRange(1);
        if(result.valid == true)
            result = ValidateRange(2);
    } 
    else if ($('#thirdRangeRadioButton').is(':checked')) {
        result = ValidateRange(1);
        if (result.valid == true)
            result = ValidateRange(2);
        if (result.valid == true)
            result = ValidateRange(3);
    }

    if (result.valid == false)
    {
        console.log(result.message);
        message = "<div class=\"well well-sm\"><div><div class=\"blink\"><strong>Validation Failed: </strong>" + result.message + "</div></div></div>";
        $('#ValidationDiv').replaceWith(message);
        blink('.blink');
        console.log(message);

        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You are replacing the element #ValidationDiv with your div in the message-variable, did you want to edit the content of the #validationDiv instead? If so use .html().

Comment: aaahhh.. i knew i was doing something silly.... I was replacing `<div id ='ValidationDiv'>` with a div that doesn't has an Id **ValidationDiv** init.. so it never gets picked up if the validation gets failed again. 

I just added id='validationDiv' inside my message text.